# Why pub upgrade don't upgrade packages and just show them

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I've got:

```
>pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies... (6.2s)
  analyzer 0.18.0 (9 newer versions available)
  angular 0.14.0
  args 0.10.0+2 (5 newer versions available)
  barback 0.13.0 (14 newer versions available)
  bootjack 0.6.5+2
  browser 0.10.0+2
  code_transformers 0.1.6 (5 newer versions available)
  collection 0.9.4 (1 newer version available)
  di 2.0.2 (3 newer versions available)
  dquery 0.7.0+4
  html5lib 0.10.0 (4 newer versions available)
  intl 0.11.9
  logging 0.9.1+1 (2 newer versions available)
  path 1.3.0
  perf_api 0.0.9
  petitparser 1.2.2
  route_hierarchical 0.4.22 (1 newer version available)
  shadow_dom 0.10.0
  source_maps 0.9.4 (1 newer version available)
  source_span 1.0.0
  stack_trace 0.9.3+2 (6 newer versions available)
  typed_mock 0.0.4
  utf 0.9.0+1
```

so I can see that `newer versions available` but so how to update them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct or transitive dependency has a version constraint that doesn't allow to use a newer version.

In Dart a package can only be imported in one version.
All dependencies need to agree on one version.

As far as I know in Java a package `A` can import package `B` version 1.0 and package `C` even when package `C` imports `B` in version 2.0.
This is not possible in Dart, the entire application has to use the same version of `B`.

To find out what prevents the upgrade I usually add a constraint in my `pubspec.yaml` that enforces the newer version.
Running `pub upgrade` then shows which dependency prevents the upgrade.

add a dependency constraint

```yaml
dependencies:
  html5lib: '>= 0.10.0'<
```

run

```bash
pub upgrade
```

inspect the result

This usually takes several iterations until the culprit can be figured out.

```bash
pub deps -s list
```

shows a helpful overview of all dependencies and constraints

You can also add a `dependency_overrides` to your `pubspec.yaml`.

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  html5lib: '>= 0.10.0'
```

to just enforce the newer version and ignore possible incompatibilities.
(http://pub.dartlang.org doesn't allow to upload packages that contain `dependency_overrides`.)