# Does dart pub upgrade, upgrades all dependencies or we have to manually change for those who got breaking changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have analyzer package that is a transitive dependency set to 2.8.0^ and latest version 3.0.0 is available.So using dart pub upgrade will upgrade it or I have to manually make it ^3.0.0 in pubspec.yaml and then run pub get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will automatically update the dependencies when you use `dart pub upgrade`

If there is a dependency say ^2.7.0 with you and there is a newer version (2.8.0) available, it will automatically upgrade to ^2.8.0 unless there is any dependency constraints.

You could use `dart pub upgrade --major-versions` so that ^2.8.0 can be upgraded to ^3.0.0.

Anyway you'll be suggested to use this command when using `dart pub upgrade`

I was upgrading `webview_flutter` from ^2.8.0 to 3.0.0:

1. I had to run `dart pub upgrade` (checked what new dependencies are there).
2. It suggested me to run `dart pub outdated`.
3. I saw `webview_flutter` was not upgraded.
4. It suggested me to run `dart pub upgrade --major-versions`.
5. I did it, and the version upgraded in `.yaml` file

Look [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-upgrade) for more about the command.

Comment: Ok got it, please tell me what do you mean by "unless there is any dependency constraints"

Comment: Dependency constraints mostly are either direct or transitive dependency. You can visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26159912/10136829) or [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-identify-and-fix-flutters-transitive-dependency-error-5141df37201) to know a bit more.

Comment: Ok thank you got it